# Is Microsoft Security Essentials a solid security suite

Tags: security, anti-virus, ms-security-essentials, anti-spyware, anti-malware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Would Microsoft Security Essentials be adequate protection?](https://superuser.com/questions/48557/would-microsoft-security-essentials-be-adequate-protection)

With the release of Microsoft's new Free security suite; Microsoft Security Essentials, the question has to be asked.  Is it worth checking out, or is it just another security suite?

Comment: Duplicate question: 'Would Microsoft Security Essentials be adequate protection?' http://superuser.com/questions/48557/would-microsoft-security-essentials-be-adequate-protection/48581#48581

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, and it is good.

I used it when it was in beta and found it very good. Since I reloaded Windows 7, I did not reinstall it due to the fact I have UAC on maximum and never install programs I don't trust.

It is brilliant - very low resource usage and works well. Now it is out of beta, I will probably be reinstalling soon.

I was previously a fan of Nod32, but recently I think they have gone down hill (More money in advertising and less in development... like another security company).