# should I install Microsofts free antivirus offering or just stay with AVG free

Tags: windows, ms-security-essentials, avg-antivirus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Would Microsoft Security Essentials be adequate protection?](https://superuser.com/questions/48557/would-microsoft-security-essentials-be-adequate-protection)

Microsoft's free antivirus program, [Security Essentials](http://www.microsoft.com/Security_essentials/), became available for download from the company's website Tuesday.

Comment: Please see: http://superuser.com/questions/48690/is-microsoft-security-essentials-a-solid-security-suite, http://superuser.com/questions/48557/would-microsoft-security-essentials-be-adequate-protection

Comment: I now understand that this is a duplicate question but why the down votes.Is it because of it being duplicated or for some other reason

Comment: I am interested in why the down votes also.

Comment: I guess partially the downvotes are for asking a question with obviously at least two duplicates and the other part are probably for even thinking about voluntarily using Microsoft security software :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use neither.  I've had great success with AVIRA.  Use that and run Malware Bytes once a week and you're in good shape.

Answer (score 0):

I would stick with AVG as it is free, has never let anything by, and is light-weight.

Also, this question will probably lead to prolonged discussion...

Comment: This answer even more with its unfounded assumptions :-)

Answer (score 0):

It may be too early to say definitively, but I've been running the MSE beta for a couple months and like it.  I upraded both home xp machines to the released code today.  ARS Technica had a positive review for it today.

\\Greg